# Totals - Minicart - JS problem

Tags: magento2, javascript, mini-cart

I have 4 errors in my shop now.

After change a plugin and did everything clearing the cache, deploy the static files, we have the error with the totals js, I should say, we bought a template and we using it, the support of them says we missed a file:

> vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals.js

The file it is there, but we cleared the cache and deploy again.

The errors is this ones:

```
/pub/static/version1521186503/frontend/Codazon/fastest_outdoor/es_ES/Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder.js 
/pub/static/version1521186503/frontend/Codazon/fastest_outdoor/es_ES/Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor.js 
/pub/static/version1521186503/frontend/Codazon/fastest_outdoor/es_ES/Magento_Msrp/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals.js
/pub/static/version1521186503/frontend/Codazon/fastest_outdoor/es_ES/Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager.js 
pub/static/version1521186503/frontend/Codazon/fastest_outdoor/es_ES/Magento_Msrp/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals.js
```

Someone knows what is that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your custom code.

Comment: the one in the template?